# Customizing default Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to send extra values along with intents with default actions like "ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" from frameworks.

I want to modify the way 'PowerUsageSummary.java' looks when it is opened via 'battery use' button click on low battery dialog box than what it looks from clicking 'battery from Settings.java

I tried putting an extra boolean in intent sent from from PowerUI.java (the class which shows the above dialog box in SystemUI package) which I am checking in PowerUsageSummary.java onReceive method.

Hence in PowerUI.java i added

```
intent.putExtra("dummy_test_key", true);
```

and in PowerUsageSummary.java I am checking it as

```
boolean b = intent.getBooleanExtra("dummy_test_key", false)
```

It seems boolean 'b' is always false as 'putExtra' didn't even work and hence returning the default false value.

What am I missing here? How do I get the actual boolean value here?

Comment: Have you read the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html? You should read the part about intent filters.

Comment: My issue is particularly with power service. I want to send an extra boolean along with the call from "powerui.java" (in frameworks/base/packages) to "powerusagesummary.java" (in packages/apps/settings) so that powerusagesummary.java could take some action if the boolean is true. Though I am able to send, but it seems this method is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow fixed the problem now. Actually I was beating the wrong bush there. I was focusing on the intent in onReceive() function which was ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED, rather than focusing on intent of fragment context ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY.